# Attempting to lift React state while maintaining access to a variable calculated lower down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I am learning React, and trying to understand exactly how much state should be lifted up to a higher level. It is my understanding that, generally speaking, a piece of state should only be lifted up if it is needed by multiple components bearing a common ancestor.

In my case, I am attempting to build a Calendar which reacts to being clicked on. The calendar itself should physically react to being clicked, but also a sidebar should show additional information on the day that was selected. Currently, the overall structure resembles this:

```
App
  Calendar
    Header
    Square
  Sidebar
    LoginInterface
```

My desired behavior leads me to believe that the App should have ownership of the `handleClick(squareNum)` method, because it could pass it down as a prop to the Squares, but the handleClick method would be able to influence the information rendered on the Sidebar. My problem arises when I attempt to raise my state up without taking essentially the entirety of the Calendar implementation with me.

Obviously, lifting up just the `handleClick(squareNum)` is problematic, because squareNum is not defined at that level. When I rendered my Squares in the Calendar, I passed them the handleClick function as a prop, along with the squareNum (literally the number of the Square in its creation during the loop). In order for handleClick to be lifted up into App, I would also need to also lift up the creation of the Squares themselves. I think that I could do that, then pass `<div>{row}</div>` down to Calendar as {props.children}, but I feel like I'm really torturing the logic of the program at that point, and not adhering to the mentality of only lifting up the code that is needed by other components.

The React docs mention something similar to my problem in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers, but I don't think that meshes perfectly here. While I do want to pass arguments to an event handler, I want to do that at a middle-level component, I want to pass the id of the Square in at Calendar but handleClick itself I want in App.

This doesn't seem like an uncommon use-case, so I feel like I must be missing something fundamental to React. Can anyone advise me on how to implement a mid-level argument into a passed-down function prop, or something along those lines?

```
class Calendar extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.setState({
      squares: Array(42).fill(null),
    })
  }

  handeClick(i){
    let squares = this.state.squares.slice()
    squares[i] = 'clicked!'
    this.setState({squares: squares})
  }

  renderSquare(squareNum){
    return(
     <Square
        //other props
        onClick={props.handleClick(squareNum)}
      />
  }

  render(){
    let squareNum = 0;
    let cal = [];

    return(
      for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
        let row = [];
        for (let j=0;j<7;j++){
          row.push(this.renderSquare(squareNum));
          squareNum++;
        }
        cal.push(<div //key //className>{row}</div>);
      }
    );
  }
}

function Square(props){
    //irrelevant for this example
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.setState=({
      renderedDate: //combined with the squareNum, this allows calculation of which day was clicked
    })

  /**HandleClick would ideally be here so that the sidebar can have the selected date passed down to it as a prop**/

  render(){
    <div>
      <Calendar //renderedDate />
      <Sidebar //props />
    </div>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you're trying to do - share information between one component and another somewhere else in the hierarchy - lifting the state up to a component that's an ancestor of both is the right thing to do. But that doesn't mean that the *handler functions* also need to be defined at that top level - that'd quickly become messy and hard-to-manage with any reasonably sized app.

All you need to have (and pass down) at the top level is the *state and state setter*. Pass the state down to the sidebar, and the state and the state setter down through the Calendar to the squares. Then, inside individual squares, define the click handler there, and call the state setter when needed.

```
// App:
  render(){
    <div>
      <Calendar renderedDate={this.state.renderedDate} />
      <Sidebar setRenderedDate={d => this.setState({ renderedDate: d }) />
    </div>
  }
```

Then pass down setRenderedDate until getting to `Square`, and have Square call that function (a prop) in its click handler.

Comment: I would highly recommend you add a react context way to do this as well.. as this is a great use case for context :)

Comment: Yeah, if the tree is really deep, it's a good option to avoid having to pass props around everywhere. The code in the question doesn't look convoluted enough to need it, but it might as the app develops further.